# ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)

Tags: git, gitlab, git-push, mingw-w64, git-remote

We recently migrated the gitlab server, the structure is working without problems via the web browser.

However, when I try to push **git push origin main** I return the following error:

`lucas_a@NB04 MINGW64 /c/temp/git/aulagitlab (main) $ git push origin main Enumerating objects: 3, done. Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done. Delta compression using up to 8 threads Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done. Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 224 bytes | 74.00 KiB/s, done. Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0 remote: GitLab: 401 Unauthorized To gitlab.domain.com.br:tecnica/aulagitlab.git ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push some refs to 'gitlab.domain.com.br:tecnica/aulagitlab.git'`

Can you help me, please?

I have already checked the permissions, and disabled Git Large File Storage (LFS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's buried in that message, but the problem here is `401 Unauthorized To gitlab.domain.com.br:tecnica/aulagitlab.git` - either you didn't provide credentials, or the credentials you provided aren't recognized. Did anything change as far as passwords or tokens?

Comment: I believe not, as we use LDAP to synchronize users (Active Directory). I just created a new Ubuntu server with the same old version and restored the backup.